# rewrite not working with godaddy after several attempts

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I Tried every possible solution suggested , still my pages are completely unaffected

My URL

http://*MyDomain*/WCOM/Flatsome/pages/about-us/

is showing 404 on godaddy server but working find on WAMP ..

I have Tried following htaccess .

1.

```
 DirectoryIndex index.php
 AddDefaultCharset utf-8

 RewriteEngine on
 Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes   

 RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.htm [L]
```

2.

```
#Fix Rewrite
Options -Multiviews

# Mod Rewrite
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) /$1.htm [L]
```

---

Nothing is working .. What Can I do More ?

Comment: Any other rules in htaccess?

Comment: Is the file you are going to rewrite to an .htm or .htm **l** ?

Comment: htm ,  my physical files are in .htm

Comment: Is mod-rewrite enabled on your godady server?

Comment: I have placed htacces files , How can I check mod-rewrite enabled/ disabled ?

Comment: @NeerajVerma you keep asking questions regarding the same problems but never acknowledge the answer people provide once you got it working. You should really follow up on your question when people take the time to answer them.

Comment: Replied you in Previous Post , and Provided answer for that Issue , this question is different

Comment: @PanamaJack ...I hope You understand you solution was not answer for me in previous post

Comment: @NeerajVerma I'm not worried about it. You got what you needed.

Comment: thats why I am not asking questions regarding the same problems if they are resolved

Comment: work Around I found is that to write the rules in WebConfig and palc it into Root Direcotry,as  I am on CPanel ,Web Hosting  ...But It is started to redirect  only for root level pages , not for Sub Directories pages

Comment: please give php info snippet if possible check if mod rewrite is enabled